# Recycler View with Grid Layout Manager and varying item span

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler View with a Grid Layout Manger. I have items with span 1 and 2 and the total span count is 2.
I need to provide a padding when the I encounter items with span 1.

I would use obviously use the ItemDecoration for the entire recycler view.
The question majorly is

> How do I differentiate between and identify a left-edged/right-edged child view when span count for the child views can vary as 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

When creating a grid with varying span, when binding data to particular view you don't know the vertical index of the particular item that is laid down, so you need to implement own logic to do that

**Solution**

I myself encountered a similar problem and solved it by providing my own logic to calculate the index of item, and it works quite well on small sized grids, but might became expensive on bigger ones

From the index I am working on I search backwards and calculate the span counts together, so I get the count of spans on the grid before any particular item, then I can take modulus of the number and the total span size to figure out which span is this particular item on, then I can decide whether the item should consume two spaces instead of one

So basically if you have this kind of grid

```
[ 1, 1 ]
[   2  ]
[ x    ]
```

And we're working on x, which we should figure the span for, we know the next item should be of size 2, and we need to decide if we need to add padding to the item.

We can calculate the position by adding together all the consumed spans, meaning spans of previous items, aka 1 + 1 + 2, which results in 4 and we can take modulus of this to figure out its span index, so we get 4 % 2.

We get the index of the previous item, meaning 0, so we know that the item is on index 1 so we should give it span of two to make the next item to drop to next line

I also posted a detailed blog post about [this](https://matalamaki.fi/2015/09/24/implementing-sticky-recyclerview-grid-headers-on-android/) which has some better illustrations and solution to the problem in actual code

Comment: I like the approach,let me try it out.

Comment: I used your approach,but tried optimizing it a bit by performing the calculation asynchronously.Thanks!